# Animating UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, core-animation, uisplitviewcontroller

```
- (IBAction)toggleMasterHidden:(id)sender
{
    isMasterHidden = !isMasterHidden;

    self.delegate = nil;
    self.delegate = self;

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}

- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc 
   shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc 
              inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return isMasterHidden;
}
```

This works fine but the results are instant. I am trying to animate the transition and am not sure the approach I should take. The following will not work because `setNeedsLayout` does not acctually change the views it just sets a flag saying to do at a later time.

```
// Does not work
[UIView beginAnimations:@"toggleMaster" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
[UIView commitAnimations];

// Also does not work, I'm assuming parent class implementation is empty
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"toggleMaster" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I am afraid I would have to create a custom splitviewcontroller to achieve this, which is a shame because I concider this a close to complete implementation.

Comment: Matt Gemmells [custom split view controller](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/) is nice option. Im not sure if it can handle animations though, you can check it out anyway!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to animate this?

Comment: @JustLearningAgain I got close but I don't remember how. I ended up not using it because there was just too many quirks.